# how to Mockup map class and mock return map.size

Tags: java, junit

I'm improving my coverage rate. So I try to enter a special condition by mock a map size, but I fail to do so. Does this method working with the original type such as map.class because I used the same method on my other class and they work fine?

```
Item i = new Item();
ItemTbl tbl = new ItemTbl();
tbl.setMerchantId(key.getMerchantId());
tbl.setBaseSku(key.getBaseSku().toUpperCase());
tbl.setOrigBaseSku(key.getBaseSku());
i.setItemTbl(tbl);
final Map<String, Item> existingItems = prepareExistingData(Arrays.asList(i), false, false);

Item existingItem;
existingItem = existingItems.get(tbl.getBaseSku());

if (existingItem == null) {
    return null; //original item api return 200 if item not found
}

if (existingItem.getShopItemMap() != null) {   
    if (existingItems.size() == 1) {
        //the thing I want to cover
    }
}
```

Junit test:

```
new MockUp<Map<String, Item>>() {
    @Mock
    public int size() {
        return 2;
    };
};

fixture.delete(entity);
```

I notice the existingItems is set as final, but I tried to delete final, but it still not work.

Comment: Which mocking framework are you using?

Comment: Why do you need to mock a `Map`? Cannot you just return a `HashMap` with two elements from your (mocked version of) `prepareExistingData` ?

Comment: @Raedwald I use mockit currently. I tried mockito, but still no luck

Comment: @Thilo Because the data are too complicated to makeup which I still need to use in if statement, and I am wonder why it doesn't work.

Comment: Rather than clarify you question in comments,  edit your question to include the extra information.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you mock the behavior of `size()` on `existingItems` specifically.
It would look something like this:

```
when(existingItems.size()).thenReturn(2);
```